# I need help executing MySQL script from a file in C# Using MySql.Data, MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

The code:

```
private static void UpdateDatabase(string filename)
{
    string DBHost = (string)ISC.Utilities.RegistryUtils.ReadRegistryValue(Constants.REMOTE_ID_KEY, Constants.REMOTE_DB_ADDRESS_VALUE);
    string DBName = (string)ISC.Utilities.RegistryUtils.ReadRegistryValue(Constants.REMOTE_ID_KEY, Constants.REMOTE_DB_NAME_VALUE);
    string DBUID = (string)ISC.Utilities.RegistryUtils.ReadRegistryValue(Constants.REMOTE_ID_KEY, Constants.REMOTE_DB_UID_VALUE);
    string DBPWD = (string)ISC.Utilities.RegistryUtils.ReadRegistryValue(Constants.REMOTE_ID_KEY, Constants.REMOTE_DB_PWD_VALUE);
    string connectionString = string.Format("SERVER={0};DATABASE={1};UID={2};PASSWORD={3}", DBHost, DBName, DBUID, DBPWD);
    MySqlConnection connection = null;

    try
    {
        string script = File.ReadAllText(filename);
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand newcCommand = new MySqlCommand(script, connection);
        newcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string str = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", ex.Message, Environment.NewLine, ex.StackTrace);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(str, "Database Error", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The script:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spMyProc;

CREATE PROCEDURE spMyProc()
BEGIN
  /* Do stuff */
END

CALL spMyProc();
DROP PROCEDURE spMyProc;
```

The error:

> ex = {"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL spMyProc();\r\nDROP PROCEDURE spMyProc' at line 6"}

I do not understand why a script so simple is causing these errors. Can you please help me.

Comment: Looks to me like your carriage return/newline (`\r\n`) is causing the issue. Either remove it from your text file, or do a `.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty)` on the string itself before executing it

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I tried that and got a slightly different error. The error with no replacement was the same if I replaced "\r\n" with " ".

Comment: Now you've posted your script, it has become a lot clearer. Take out the `Replace` suggestion, for now. You are missing a `;` after `END` :) Should work (if not, put the `Replace` back in) Let me know how you get on

Comment: OMG, that simple. Thank you. So why doesn't workbench complain about the missing ";" ?

Comment: You're welcome! It's _always_ something so simple, don't worry. I've posted it as an answer, also :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a semi-colon `;` after your declaration of your stored procedure.

Add it after `END`. Your code should now look like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spMyProc;

CREATE PROCEDURE spMyProc()
BEGIN
  /* Do stuff */
END;

CALL spMyProc();
DROP PROCEDURE spMyProc;
```

Hope this helps! :)